# finding eigenvalues of a linear transformation and determine if its diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation such that $T(a_1,a_2,a_3) = (-3a_3, a_1+5a_3,a_2-a_3)$.
>
> (i) Find all the eigenvalues of T
>
> (ii) For each eigenvalue $\alpha$, write $E_\alpha$ as a span of some basis.
>
> (iii) Is T diagnolizable?

This is my solution. Is it correct?
First, we find the standard matrix representation.

The standard basis $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$, $e_3=(0,0,1)$

Then the images of these vectors are
$T(e_1) = (0,1,0)$, $T(e_2) = (0,0,1)$, $T(e_3) = (-3,5,-1)$

Hence the standard matrix representation is given by:

$[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & -3\\
1 & 0 & 5\\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{matrix}]
$

now we need to find the eigenvalues:

Solve $|M-\alpha I|=0$ for $\alpha$, you get $\alpha^3 + \alpha^2-5\alpha=-3$. the roots are $\alpha_1=1, \alpha_2=-3,\alpha_3=1$ which are the eigenvectors.

(ii) To find $E_1$ and $E_{-3}$, we compute $E_1=Null(M-\alpha_1 I)$ and $E_3=Null(M-alpha_3 I)$ which turns to be:
$E_1 = span \{(-1,2,1)\}$ and $E_3 = span \{(1,-2,1)\}$

(iii) To determine if the matrix is diagnolizable, we compute roots of $det(\alpha I-M)=0$, which turns to be the polynomial $\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 -5\alpha + 3=0$ and this has the roots 1, -3, 1. Since they are not distinct then the matrix is not diagonlizable.

Comment: Your roots do not match the polynomial you wrote.

Comment: thanks. Is it correct now?

Comment: identity matrix has repeating eigenvalues. what you need for diagonalizablity is to have an eigenbasis. that the is sum of the dimensions of the null spaces add up to the dimension of the whole sapce.

Comment: I see. so the dimension of an eigenspace is its multiplicity. hence, $dim(E_1)+dim(E_{-3})=2+1=3=dim(\mathbb{R}^3)$. @abel

Comment: there are two types of multiplicity:(i) algebraic multiplicity, (ii) geometric multiplicity. algebraic multiplicity is the number of times the eiegenvalue repeats. geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the null space associated with that eigenvalue.  in the case of eigenvalue $-1,$ you have algebraic multiplicity $2$ and geometric multiplicity $1$ because rank of $(A-I)$ is two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The criterion for a matrix $T$ to be diagonalisable is either:

- The dimension of each eigenspace $E_\alpha$  is equal to the multiplicity $m_1$ of $\alpha$ as a root of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{T}(x)$, or:
- Each eigenvalue $\alpha$ is a *simple* root of the minimal polynomial of $T$.

*First method:*

Using row-reduction, we obtain:
$$I-T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&3\\-1&1&-5\\0&-1&2\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&3\\0 &1&-2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
This matrix has rank 2, hence $\dim E_1=1< m_1=2$. So $T$  is *not * diagonisable.

Moreover, solving the system, we find a basis for $E_1$ is the vector:
$$\begin{bmatrix}-3\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

*Second method:*
If the matrix is diagonalisable, its minimal polynomial must be $(x-1)(x+3)=x^2+2x-3=(x+1)^2-4$, hence $T$ must satisfy $(T+I)^2=4I$. However
$$(T+I)^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3\\1&1&5\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&-3\\2&6&2\\1&1&5\end{bmatrix}.$$